# Create specific/new Definitely Typed for PhpStorm to support auto-complete

Tags: javascript, typescript, autocomplete, phpstorm, definitelytyped

I think about 'Definitely Typed' which PhpStorm, WebStorm,.. used for autocomplete.

```
In PhpStorm: Settings > Languages and frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries : Download
```

I know from [GitHub:DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/) that it's written in TypeScript.

But the question: if I create my own lib in JavaScript and I need to active auto-complete for it, so if it has run time binding of variables and method : PhpStorm will not detect it so I need to write my own typescript file to do it: How?

Comment: unfortunately your question is little bit hard to understand. Please try to add some examples & rephrase your question

Comment: it's very simple : if you need to active autocomplete for function and variables from library/framework like express in nodejs : php storm will not support autocomplete for inherited function so you just go to  Settings >> Libraries : then download express typescript file to support auto-complete : so i write some js libraries based on inheritance so phpstorm/webstorm will not auto-complete my object function : so i need to write typescript file and add it to the ide to support auto-complete for my lib

Comment: Yes. You have to create a library stub with all your types defined - it can be a TypeScript `d.ts` file or `.js` file with method stubs (you can annotate then with JSDoc to provide explicit info about types) - and add it as a JavaScript library in PhpStorm (or just place it in your project) to get completion